# External files with Content-type application/vnd.ms-excel

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel, download

I am trying to download a .xls when I click a button on my website for this it is loading another page with

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

in the php file

I am also using certain libraries to generate the text that is to be presented in the xls file

```
echo "<script src = '.....'></script>"
```

When I remove the header part then the data is presented correctly in the browser
but with the header I sometimes get the error "missing files <relative path added to my Downloads folder>",
but the text is never present in the xls file which I am generating using the external javascript files

I believe when downloading they make the downloads folder the root and want all the external files to be present on my computer instead of the server

How can I work around this?
Thank you

Comment: `<script>` is an HTML tag. Why would you include that in a binary file format like the old Excel XLS file format?

Comment: I have a php file which creates the xls file which is to be downloaded, for that I set the header to have the content-type vnd.ms-excel and then to get the data I want to use a javascript library,

Comment: Okay... how does the Javascript data get to PHP so it can generate the XLS file? Or let me ask a different question: when you download the XLS file and open it in a text editor like Notepad, do you see binary gibberish or a HTML document?

Comment: @rickdenhaan I am opening the xls file in ms-excel and all the other data that is not generated by the library is presented in it correctly, I am just using the PHP to use a bunch of echo statements that is generating a html, javascript code